# XML Can't Encrypted For Connection String

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have project for Connection DB, im created db.config for connection to SQLExpress but why after run the apps, Connection String can't encrypted

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MFSiExDbConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Provider>MsSql2008</Provider>
  <ConnectionString>Server=CAPS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HFD_DB;User Id=HFD;Password=OraS1m$1</ConnectionString>
</MFSiExDbConfig>
```

Please help to fix this

Comment: `MFSiExDbConfig` is not a standard configuration section and this doesn't look like a standard configuration file. If you want to encrypt it, you'll have to actually build encryption support in the application processing this file.

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you help me for that and tell me which part?

Comment: That's too much to fit in an answer on Stack Overflow, I'm afraid. There are some questions on here that deal with it, but they're all sufficiently flawed that I wouldn't want to link to them. If you lack the programming know-how, consider using the built-in features of the OS like Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) or securing the file with appropriate permissions; there's far less ways to go wrong with that.